blind deconvolution of astronomy images
Hubble's angular resolution is 0.04 arc seconds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution
The closest star has an angular diameter of 1.02 milliarc seconds. https://space.fandom.com/wiki/Proxima_Centauri
So, in most images of stars, each star should be approximately 1 pixel wide due to discretization (of course with variable intensity localized to that pixel), assuming we could remove the noise from the imaging system.
Has anyone had success with blind deconvolution (or other techniques) given images of stars with the cross telescope artifacts? I am attaching an image that I was not able to deconvolve.


Of course, if an object is less than a pixel in angular diameter, it can be divided between adjacent pixels in an image, but given the ratio of imaging resolution to object resolution for stars, this should not be very prevalent.

Yes, people have been successful with deconvolution. Likely not blind deconvolution, as you can easily derive the PSF from these systems. One problem with your image is that many pixels are clipped, you don’t know the true intensity of those pixels.

@Cris Luengo Good point about the clipping.
